# How to export Facebook birthdays permanently?

Tags: facebook, google-calendar

I found the obvious information about how to 'import' Facebook birthdays into Google Calendar. Yet, this is not a true export/import, it just shows the Facebook birthdays in my Google Calendar without really copying the information.

I am leaving Facebook and I don't wish to lose all my friends' birthdays. How can I achieve this?

The link in the comments provides the same solution that I can find when googling the problem, but as I said, this does NOT copy the data, it just creates a dynamic URL link to it. The result will be that if I delete my facebook account, this iCal will disappear.

**I am looking for a way to permanently EXPORT the birthdays and then IMPORT them** as real data into my regular Google Calendar. I do not want an iCal link.

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/help/206619532710687/

Comment: Why would it be dynamic? It just gets updated as long as you have Facebook. As soon as it gone, Google Calendar will have it. At least this happened when I lost my RTM account. Give it a try. Add a URL (from anywhere) and then remove the URL (disable sharing on the site?).

Comment: Wait, I got the popular question batch for this but it doesn't have a single upvote? How does Stack Exchange even work outside of the original trilogy :o

Comment: Popular = people visit it. Upvoted questions mean different badges again. :)

Comment: Well, I know that... but usually the two correlate higher, at least on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, Facebook does not provides any such option, so it is not possible.

At the maximum, Facebook does has an API, so it must be possible through the API, but then, you have already gone through the apps and they are providing only dynamic links and not actually copying the data.

So, what you are left with is - make your own app to copy birthdays using the Faceboom API or else, you can always manually copy and paste the data from Facebook to Google Calender or may be iCal or any other software system of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a site which creates an iCalendar file from the facebook birthday page.
This is the hardcopy you are looking for:
https://maltejoos.github.io/Facebook-Birthday-Export/